# App and environment config in separate repos in GitOps - how to handle config changes?

Tags: continuous-deployment, argocd, gitops

I've begun a GitOps journey with k8s and argoCD using separate repos for app source and deployment files (manifests, environment config, etc), and I'm trying to figure out, how I would ensure a succesful deployment, if an application source code change also requires a change in environment config.

Example: an application is deployed and running on a test/QA environment, and I want to push a code change, which requires a new "DB_ConnectionString" environment variable.
Since this environment variable is new, it doesn't exist in my deployment/gitops repo's config files (let's say it's a Helm values-QA.yml).

If I push this new code change, the CI will build the application and update the container, which prompts argoCD to deploy the new container version - but because I haven't updated the GitOps repo, it's missing this new variable, and the deployment will fail.

I guess I'm struggling to understand, if in these cases, I'm forced to always ensure that my GitOps repo is updated before my app repo, and whether there's a best practice to handle this flow?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation.  My experience is with everything existing in the same repo.  This makes testing your app in local k8s very easy with tools like tilt.  Then you know everything is proper.  I much prefer the workflow that is driven by artifact creation.  If you want something published, you make a new image/artifact.  if not, then don't.  Argo basically suggests a new commit to force a change.  Which, if automated, probably means one repo's pipeline will write a commit to another repo using sed?  My best advice for this workflow is that the same team should own both repos.